# when I fetch API_URL from .env as an environment variable, I get an error. I have dotenv installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

.env

```
REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=mytoken
API_URL=http://localhost:1377
```

.js

```
// const API_URL = "http://localhost:1337";

export async function listLogEntries() {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/routes`);
  return response.json();
}

export async function createLogEntry(entry) {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/routes`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(entry),
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

When I fetch API_URL from .env file I get an error: **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

But If I use API_URL right away from .js file

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:1337";
export async function listLogEntries() {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/routes`);
  return response.json();
}

export async function createLogEntry(entry) {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/routes`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(entry),
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

I don't get that error and my app work as well

Comment: Refer the below links:

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but it looks like `process.env.API_URL` isn't actually getting defined correctly. The "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error generally means fetch is getting a 404 not found error (which is actually an html page), and trying to interpret it as JSON. I'd try logging the value of `process.env.API_URL` to the console to verify that it's being pulled in correctly.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your support, I did what u said, I got undefined. Might I asked, How can I interpret it as JSON?

Comment: @key, the problem is not how it's being interpreted; it's what's being sent. You're getting a 404 html message because *the address isn't valid.* Give `fetch` a valid address (as you do in your second example), and you won't get the html 404 error.

So, what you need to do first is figure out what value `process.env.API_URL` actually has at runtime in your code. If you haven't tried calling `console.log(process.env.API_URL` just before you run your `fetch` call, as I mentioned above, I suggest you try that.

Answer (score 1):

You might not implementing dotenv correctly. I implment it this way: Making the topmost import in the server.js file of my node project with the path to the env file. Check it below :-

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
```

[image]

The env file looks like :-

[image]

And i am able to use the .env file correctly within the project.

You can check the complete blog out [here](https://itnext.io/manage-environment-variables-in-your-nodejs-application-with-dotenv-520914a9254b).

The env module i used is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: thanks for your support, I did what you suggest but didn't work bro